# Unable to get request.referer to return value other than nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4

So far I have been unable to get request.referer to return the refering URL (which in this case would point to the first method). I used both mobile and desktop browers (Firefox, Opera, Safari, Chrome) and so far have been unable to get a non-nil value returned.

```
def first
  redirect_to test_path
end


def second
  @r = request.referer
end
```

Comment: you're going to have to provide a more complete example than that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for referer:

```
request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
```